# flutter-web) how to capture whole screen and save it to gallery

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am running a project with a flutter web
and i need to capture whole screen and save it directly to gallery or photos

but the methods and packages what I have used downloads only as a file

does anyone knows some packages or methods to capture screen and save directly to the gallery??

Answer (score 0):

Do you try this package: [ScreenShot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot)